# Drawing sprites to a permanent Texture2d using Monogame / XNA

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, texture2d

*(Cross post from Gamedevs)*

I'm working with Monogame to do a 2d sprite engine. I've gotten it work pretty well where I can move lots of sprites around the screen with the effects and positions that I want.

Last night I tried to add a feature and I can't quite get it to work right.
I'm trying to create permanent trails that the moving sprites can leave behind. So I have a mostly transparent PNG with some white lines on it called "streak". The idea is that I set up a new `Texture2D` surface (called streakoverlay) and I draw the streaks on to it.

I switch back to the back buffer and draw: The background, the streakoverlay, and finally the sprite on top of it. The streaks should build up over time. It almost works, but the trouble I have is that `streakOverlay` seems to clear itself every time. How I'd like it to behave would be the same behaviour as having the graphics display without this line `GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);` - everything would just pile up in it.

Instead it resets back to the `Purple` transparent color that is the default for that texture. Any suggestions? Here's the core piece of the rendering engine:

```
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
RenderTarget2D streakOverlay;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

private Texture2D bkg;
private Texture2D prototype;
private Texture2D streak;

//Initialize 
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);
streakOverlay = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, 200,200);

//Load Content
bkg = Content.Load<Texture2D>("bkg"); //Background image
prototype = Content.Load<Texture2D>("prototype"); //Prototype sprite that moves around
streak = Content.Load<Texture2D>("blueStreak"); //Trails being left by Prototype sprite

graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(streakOverlay); 
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent); //Attempt to make the streakoverlay is fully transparent.
graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

//Draw
Random r = new Random();
graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(streakOverlay); //Switch to drawing to the streakoverlay

spriteBatch.Begin();
//Draw some streaks that should accumulate
spriteBatch.Draw(streak, new Vector2(r.Next(0, 200), r.Next(0, 200)), null, Color.White, 0f, new Vector2(25, 25), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
spriteBatch.End();

//Switch back to drawing on the back buffer.
graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(bkg, new Rectangle(0, 0, 2000, 2000), Color.White);    //Draw our background
spriteBatch.Draw(streakOverlay, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White); //Put the overlay on top of it
spriteBatch.Draw(prototype, new Vector2(_spritePrototype.getX, _spritePrototype.getY), null, Color.White, DegreeToRadian(rotationSprite), new Vector2(25, 25), .5f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f); //Draw the sprite that's moving around.
spriteBatch.End();

base.Draw(gameTime);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the extended constructor for RenderTarget2D that takes 4 parameters and specify PreserveContents. The assumption is that render targets are often reused and so when it is set it gets cleared automatically unless this flag is set.